# Add tooltip for PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, propertygrid

I want to add a tool tip for items in a Property Grid. When the user hovers over a property I want the tooltip to display a hint about the usage of that property. The hint string should be different for each different value of the property — for example if one property is a list of strings each string would have a different hint.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The PropertyGrid is not very flexible and doesn't expose any of the individual controls on it.  You can access the control (textbox or dropdown) that you're looking to show the tooltip on via reflection but that is far from trivial, especially since all the control classes are unique and internal to the property grid.

Using the Description attribute is by far the best value.  If your list of strings for that property aren't obvious enough to portray their meaning without providing a tooltip, perhaps you should revisit the string text you are showing for each item in the list.